# Webkit Style sharing and sibling selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors, webkit

Learning CSS i came across this document: How Browsers Work: [Behind the scenes of modern web browsers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/#w3c)
Regarding to style sharing it states the following:

> Sharing style data
>
> WebKit nodes references style objects (RenderStyle) These objects can
>   be shared by nodes in some conditions. The nodes are siblings or
>   cousins and:
>
> 1. The elements must be in the same mouse state (e.g., one can't be in :hover while the other isn't).
> 2. Neither element should have an id
> 3. The tag names should match
> 4. The class attributes should match
> 5. The set of mapped attributes must be identical
> 6. The link states must match
> 7. The focus states must match
> 8. Neither element should be affected by attribute selectors, where affected is defined as having any selector match that uses an
>      attribute selector in any position within the selector at all
> 9. There must be no inline style attribute on the elements
> 10. There must be no sibling selectors in use at all. WebCore simply throws a global switch when any sibling selector is encountered and
>       disables style sharing for the entire document when they are present.
>       This includes the + selector and selectors like :first-child and
>       :last-child.

What is particularly interesting is the 10th rule stating any single sibling selector in the entire document will disable the entire style sharing feature completely.

I could not find any documentation for sibling selectors being a bad practice, or the importance of style sharing.
Can anyone explain how important style sharing really is ?

Comment: "I could not find any documentation for sibling selectors being a bad practice, or the importance of style sharing." Maybe because it's an implementation detail? Personally, I'm wondering if this explains why sibling selectors are so buggy on WebKit.

Comment: Reading the same article, I wondered about this too. If style sharing is used as a performance optimisation and it's disabled when a single sibling selector is used, what is the performance hit?